# PHP - Variable vs Array Call

Tags: php, memory, process

Say I have an array `$order` containing the data of entire order and user as well.

To display the name of user; I use `$order['users'][33]['firstname'];`. I do this in several parts of page.

Does it really matter to the memory and process to do this way (using associative array)? Or should I store user in a variable

`$user = $order['users'][33]['firstname'];`

and keep using $user where ever needed? Which method is prefered?

Comment: i believe there is no big difference. Using variable is just simple instead of writing that much long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what your application does. If `$order` contains only one user and every subarray contain only one data value, then store the information in variables and give them readable names. Otherwise, if `$order` contains many users and information are kind of a tree, then array is definitely a good way to implement your application. In terms of memory consumption, as long as you are storing the same amount of information I don't think it will be a crucial difference.